CoreBluetooth missing advertising data on iPhone vs Mac
I'm using CoreBluetooth to listen to advertising data to extract the bytes I need from the BLE device I have, specifically the manufacturer data.
I've verified my application and the code as working via Mac as a silicon app and I get the bytes as intended, however on my iPhone running the exact same code, the manufacturer data is not there, the entire key is missing.
Is there anything obvious I've missed? There are other apps that have this data and are able to extract it. I've added an image below of the BLE data from the nRF Connect app.

centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])

...

if let manufacturerData = fullAdvertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] as? Data {
    ... // No bytes on iPhone so it doesn't call in here.
}


Are you trying to remove the options at the scanForPeripherals initializer?
For example: centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)

@MohammadBarznji I'm not sure what you mean by this, the option I have set is to avoid the filtering CB does on potential duplicates to ensure I don't miss the data..., with what you're suggesting I'd could miss the advertisement.

Is your desired data broadcasted in the Advertising Data or the Scan Response Data?

@Emil It’s in the advertising data

@Owen, I apologize for the inconvenience. This repository might be helpful. It’s a small project that scans BLE devices and displays the information. FLY
GitHub link: BLEScanner

On iOS I discovered that iBeacons advertisement data are not available via the CoreBluetooth stack, they're stripped out by the framework. The correct way to get advertisement data is to use CoreLocation, which is likely (depending on the manufacturer and device), is in the minor and major values that are broadcasted.
On MacOS iBeacons and Bluetooth advertisement data remains available in CoreBluetooth and CoreLocation.

It looks like you've used Apple's CIC (0x004C) in your Manufacturer Specific Data. You should use your own CIC. I haven't tested this, but it would not surprise me if Apple consumes things labeled as theirs rather than passing it on to the app.
If you're trying to advertise as an iBeacon, those generally do not appear in CoreBluetooth. They are reported by CoreLocation.
